# QT creator | How to read a directory(path) by using line edit?

Tags: c++, qt, path, directory

Here's the code I am using :

```
void Dialog::on_pushButton_clicked()  
{
    QString directory = QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory(this,  
                           tr("Find Files"), QDir::currentPath());  
    ui->lineEdit->setText(directory);  
}
```

With this, I can display a list of files of a path given directly. How can I make this code display the list of files for a directory/path given by the user?

Answer (score 0):

Declare a `QDir` like this : `QDir dir(directory)` and then use [QDir::entryList()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdir.html#entryList) (which returns a list of the names of all the files and directories in the directory).